# What are the differences between Custom Tag Libraries and Core Tag Libraries in JSP?

Tags: jsp

What is the difference between Custom Tag Libraries and Core Tag Libraries in JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom tag libraries are homegrown tag libraries. Core tag libraries are part of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (JSP Standard Tag Library). You can find an overview of them all in the [JSTL taglib documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). It's the [JSTL core](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) one. It just offers a set of tags which are likely to be very commonly used to control the flow/output of a JSP page. Here's an extract of relevance:

> ## JSTL core
>
> ---
>
> #### Standard Syntax:
>
> ```
>     <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
> ```
>
> #### XML Syntax:
>
> ```
>     <anyxmlelement xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" />
> ```
>
> ---
>
> JSTL 1.1 core library
>
> ### Tag Library Information
>
> - Display Name: JSTL core
> - Version: 1.1
> - Short Name: c
> - URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
>
> ### Tag Summary
>
> - `catch` Catches any Throwable that occurs in its body and optionally exposes it.
> - `choose`    Simple conditional tag that establishes a context for mutually exclusive conditional operations, marked by `<when>` and `<otherwise>`
> - `if`    Simple conditional tag, which evalutes its body if the supplied condition is true and optionally exposes a Boolean scripting variable representing the evaluation of this condition
> - `import`    Retrieves an absolute or relative URL and exposes its contents to either the page, a String in 'var', or a Reader in 'varReader'.
> - `forEach`   The basic iteration tag, accepting many different collection types and supporting subsetting and other functionality
> - `forTokens` Iterates over tokens, separated by the supplied delimeters
> - `out`   Like `<%= ... >`, but for expressions.
> - `otherwise` Subtag of `<choose>` that follows  tags and runs only if all of the prior conditions evaluated to 'false'
> - `param` Adds a parameter to a containing 'import' tag's URL.
> - `redirect`  Redirects to a new URL.
> - `remove`    Removes a scoped variable (from a particular scope, if specified).
> - `set`   Sets the result of an expression evaluation in a 'scope'
> - `url`   Creates a URL with optional query parameters.
> - `when`  Subtag of `<choose>` that includes its body if its condition evalutes to 'true'

#### See also:

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - Using JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html)
- [Java EE 5 tutorial - Custom tags in JSP pages](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html)

*Note that [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) doesn't mention about them anywhere as JSP is considered to be "legacy". It's not officially deprecated though, the focus is just more put on Facelets, the successor of JSP, and the MVC framework JSF.*